# iOS Collection copy print different address in NSArray and NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, memory-address

here is the code.

```
NSArray *someArray = @[@"2222"];
NSArray *shallowCopyArray = [someArray copyWithZone:nil];

NSLog(@"someArray address: %p", someArray);
NSLog(@"shallowCopyArray address: %p", shallowCopyArray);

NSDictionary *someDictionary = @{@"11": @"22"};
NSDictionary *shallowCopyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:someDictionary copyItems:NO];

NSLog(@"someDictionary address: %p", someDictionary);
NSLog(@"shallowCopyDict address: %p", shallowCopyDict);
```

and I get the prints:

```
someArray address: 0x618000000910
shallowCopyArray address: 0x618000000910
someDictionary address: 0x6180000227c0
shallowCopyDict address: 0x6180000228a0
```

both are shallow copy, why NSArray print the same address while NSDictionary print different address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two completely different methods for making the copies. For the array, you use `copyWithZone:` on the array. Since it's an immutable array, it simply returns `self`.

For the dictionary, you are using `alloc/init`. This creates a new instance but with the same contents.

If you used `alloc/init` on the array, you would probably also get a new array. And if you used `copyWithZone:` on the dictionary, you would probably get the same dictionary back.